# Rails has_many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many

I have the following models:

Category:
has_many :sub_categories

Sub_Category:
has_many :posts

Post:
belongs_to :sub_category

I'm trying to build a page that will list Categories with Pjax tabs and each Category tab will list all it's Sub-Categories in widgets with 5 posts in each widget.

Question 1: Do I need a has_many_through association with Posts on the Category controller to achieve this (as well as a join table)?

Question 2: How do I structure this query? I've been searching for a while now for some direction

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget the `belongs_to :category` in `sub_category` model.

You can do something like this (it's not fast, so be careful):

```
@category.sub_categories.each do |sub_cat|
  sub_cat.posts.each_slice(5) do |posts|
    #here you create a widget, posts have at most 5 elements thanks to each_slice method
    posts.each do |post|
      #do something with each post
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did forget the belongs_to :category. I'm putting this one the home page so do I need to place this in the Application Controller?

Comment: You put this in the view, using `<% %>` and you get the @category in your controller.

Comment: Ok, I'm routing the Posts controller to the home page but this needs to go in the Category controller right? If so, do I need to add it to application controller so I can access it in Posts?

Comment: You can get the category of a post doing: `@category = post.sub_category.category`

Comment: Because the query starts with category should I change the root to go to category index? Currently I'm running it in Posts and I get: undefined local variable or method `category'

Comment: It would be good if you change your root to category index if you can.

Comment: I switched root to category index but I'm getting this error: undefined method `sub_categories' for nil:NilClass